# I have problem with wine. How to remove and reinstall a fresh working wine?

Tags: wine

```
Linux X18 5.19.0-46-generic #47~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 21 15:35:31 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Ubuntu :No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Example of windows application use to run minidb13.exe:

```
erik@X18:~/wine/Program Files (x86)/mini dB-Calculator$ wine minidb13.exe
/usr/bin/wine: 40: exec: /usr/lib/wine/wine: not found

file /usr/lib/wine/wine
/usr/lib/wine/wine: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=bdc6c22a72c47a34f37bb4879d3872398bbee76d, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

Comment: Please [edit] your questionand be more specific. What problem do you have? How exactly did you install `wine`?

Comment: I have used wine for some nice applications and suddenly, maybe Linux-update don't know for sure. The applications don't work. Tried to remove wine using "Ubuntu Software" and reinstall. Did not help. Tried Synaptic packet handler and remove a lot of "wine..". Tried to reinstall with Synaptic but no success. That's why a ask Ubuntu...

Comment: Please avoid commenting on your own question. Edit your question instead. Comments are intended to help you improve your question until it is answerable.

Comment: **Please [edit] your question to add requested information.** Don't use comments for this purpose. Can you re-install the "nice applications"? Naming these "nice applications" and specifying in which way they "don't work" might also help.

Comment: The error message shows that you cannot run the `wine` program itself, it is not related to the Windows program. The executable is a 32-bit version while your system is 64-bit. "*x86_64* GNU/Linux" vs. "/usr/lib/wine/wine: *ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386*" I guess the 32-bit binary lacks some 32-bit libraries. I think that the package management would either install the 64-bit version or install the required libraries. How exactly did you install `wine`? What exactly means "Tried to reinstall with Synaptic but *no success*"? What exactly did you do, what happened?